# Error recognising variable in dataset after attaching it

Tags: r

The following is a segment of code that I need to perform so that in the later stages I can perform other functions to make histograms of the dataset. My problem is that even after correctly importing the dataset, it does not recognize the "Aboard" Variable.[image: Proof that i have imported the dataset correctly and that the variable "abroad" exists]
 This clearly shows that the variable exists and that the dataset has been imported properly but whenever i try and run the chunks the second chunk comes up with an error saying that it does not recognise the variable. I have also tried to do this with another variable and it comes up with the same error. I do not know why it is happening and if it it because i have missed out a step. I tried to fix this by putting the line`colnames(before)` in but it did no good.

````
setwd("~/Uni Y2/Stats/Group Project")

Before <- read.csv("before_911_no_summary.csv",header = TRUE)

After <- read.csv("after_911_no_summary.csv",header = TRUE)

colnames(Before) <-c("Date","Location","Aboard","Fatalities","Ground", 
"Total.dead")
colnames(After) <-c("Date1","Location1","Aboard1","Fatalities1","Ground1", 
"Total.dead1")

```
```{r}
Survivors<- (Aboard-Fatalities) 
Survivors1<- (Aboard1-Fatalities1) 

```
````

Comment: Code in your RMD file does **not** use the variables in the RStudio environment if you "build" (render) but I guess you "just" wanted to prove the columns do exist. Can you please add the exact code fragment that is causing the error + the exact error msg to your question? In the shown code junk you read a `data.frame` but try to access the variables inside the `data.frame` without giving the `data.frame` variable name. Try `Survivors <- (Before$Aboard - Before$Fatalities)` etc.